# MasterCard Hosted Checkout Integration SECURITY

Tags: mastercard

as you know, the documentation indicates tha we need a javascipt like this:

```
Checkout.configure({
              session: { 
                id: '<your_create_checkout_session_ID>'
                },
              interaction: {
                    merchant: {
                        name: 'Your merchant name',
                        address: {
                            line1: '200 Sample St',
                            line2: '1234 Example Town'            
                        }    
                    }
               }
        });
```

, as it is javascript in an HTML, everyone can see our Merchant_id and the session_id,etc.

How can we hide this info ??

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you shouldn't use this type of information and configuration in your Front-end application/client because of the security issue that you mentioned.

Instead of that, use these steps:

1. remove all implementation like **configuration**, **checkout**, **double-check payments**, etc. from your client.
2. implement them into your `backend-application` / `server` (as a service or microservice)
3. use the usual `REST API` to communicate between your client and server applications

hope to be useful in your case.

Comment: Hi, hope all is well. I currently have a Nodejs backend and a React Native expo CLI frontend. when the users clicks on Add card on the frontend i send an api call to backend to create a session then take its response and send it back to frontend to open a webview that is linked to an index.html file on my frontend. do you suggest that i move my index.html to my backend as well then use the Webview to render the url from my backend?

Comment: @kd12345 thanks, yes you could do that without issues.